# About value object and spring

Tags: java, spring

It seems that the value object or data transfer object don't need to managed by spring.

the value object is simple enough and don't have any ctor.

the "new object" style is good enough and simple.

is it?

any advice is welcome, thx.

Comment: DTOs should not be managed by Spring. Use Spring to manage your business logic (service) classes.

Comment: Generally, this is correct.  A typical Value Object (also known as data transfer object) is just a collection of getters, setters, and properties with no business logic and a short (or at least well-defined) lifetime.  These are usually created by the data source (the object that is the source of the data) and not in spring.